# Write a query to identify frequent posters

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that will find the `user_id`'s of all users
that have created a minimum of two posts in a maximum of 1 hour.

Here's a light example of the data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_posts
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `created_date` datetime);

INSERT INTO tbl_posts
    (`id`, `user_id`, `created_date`)
    VALUES
    (1, 1, '2021-07-01 09:00'),

    (2, 2, '2021-07-01 10:15'), -- *
    (3, 2, '2021-07-01 11:00'), -- * user posted twice within an hour.

    (4, 3, '2021-07-01 13:00'), 
    (5, 3, '2021-07-01 15:00'),
    (6, 3, '2021-07-01 18:00'),
    
    (7, 4, '2021-07-01 11:00'),
    (8, 4, '2021-07-02 11:30'),
    (9, 4, '2021-07-03 12:30'), -- *
    (10, 4, '2021-07-03 12:45'); -- * user posted twice within an hour.
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e7cba

The expected output of the query is

```
2, 4
```

This output is expected because users 2 and 4 have each posted at least twice in under an hour.

I don't know where to begin with this in MySQL.  I can export the data and get a result procedurally in something like C or Python, but I'm sure this is accomplishable in MySQL and am curious to know how. Maybe I need a Window function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know about `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM tbl_posts t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tbl_posts t2
  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    AND t1.created_date < t2.created_date
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.created_date, t2.created_date) <= 60 * 60
)
```

Or, if your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `LEAD()` window function:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (
  SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(
              SECOND, 
              created_date, 
              LEAD(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_date)
            ) diff
  FROM tbl_posts          
) t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MIN(diff) <= 60 * 60
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=856c8b102f11d9b522d881d93790e29c).

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct p.user_id from tbl_posts p
inner join tbl_posts p2 on p.user_id = p2.user_id 
and p.created_date < p2.created_date
and DATE_ADD(p.created_date,interval 1 hour) >= p2.created_date
```